# How to override set property in npoco?

Tags: c#, asp.net, npoco

I have a class such as

```
public class Person {
  public int age {get;set;}
  public string ageText {get;set;}
}
```

When npoco selects age from the database, I want to override it such that it also runs a function and sets ageText. So if it tries to set age to 25, it will in addition run a function as as :

```
function setAgeAsText(age) {
 this.ageAsText = "Twenty five"
}
```

Comment: Why not add another property to the `Person` class and call it something like `AgeAsText` that runs the function and returns the age in the format you want.

Comment: @CallMeKags I need agAsText property only when it's returned to json, and would prefer calling extra methods in the controller before objects are returned :) but yes, that's the current solution.